# tpot error message when running the dataset for TPOT

Tags: broadcast, tpot

When tpot gives the following error.
could not broadcast input array from shape (80) into shape (50)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the issue is not the dataset but the selection of tpot for classification. Then realize the issue is nothing to do with the dataset. once the TPOT use for regression problem by using TPOTRegressor things start to work. Thanks to every one.

from tpot import TPOTRegressor